# 3 packages that are not upgraded are preventing Ubuntu 19.10 from being upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 19.04, 19.10, do-release-upgrade

I found instructions for the upgrade on [Focal Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes), but when I follow them, they don't work.  The steps I followed along with their outputs:

> - You can upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from either Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or
>   Ubuntu 19.10.
> - Ensure that you have all updates installed for your current version
>   of Ubuntu before you upgrade.

Output of `sudo apt update`:

```
$ sudo apt update  
Get:2 https //download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease [43.0 kB]  
Hit:1 https //packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease  
Hit:3 http //old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease  
Hit:4 http //old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease  
Hit:5 http //old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease  
Hit:6 http //old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease  
Fetched 43.0 kB in 3s (15.9 kB/s)  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
42 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

> - Confirm that you also have a network connectivity to one of the     official mirrors or to a locally accessible mirror as there are no   offline upgrade options.

```
$ wget mirror.enzu.com.ubuntu  
--2021-02-15 22:33:09--  http://mirror.enzu.com.ubuntu/  
Resolving <MIRROR NAME> (<MIRROR NAME>)... 92.242.140.21  
Connecting to <MIRROR NAME> (<MIRROR NAME>)|92.242.140.21|:80... connected.  
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK  
Length: unspecified [text/html]  
Saving to: ‘index.html’  
  
index.html                                          [ <=>                                                                                                   ]     894  --.-KB/s    in 0s  

2021-02-15 22:33:09 (9.06 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [894]
```

> - Install `update-manager-core` if it is not already installed.

```
$ sudo apt install update-manager-core  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:19.04.8).  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

> - Make sure the Prompt line in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` is set to 'normal' if you are using 19.10, or 'lts' if you are using 18.04 LTS.

```
$ grep Prompt /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades  
Prompt=normal
```

> - Launch the upgrade tool with the command `sudo do-release-upgrade`

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade  
Checking for a new Ubuntu release  
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.  
For upgrade information, please visit:  
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife  

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

What have I done wrong?  I edited the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point it to the `old-releases.ubuntu.com` URLs and it appears that the `apt update` was successful.  Why would the instructions say that I can do it from a particular version only to tell me that I can't do it because I am coming from that version?

Any help in explaining this to me would be most appreciated.

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade  
[sudo] password for dalex:  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
Calculating upgrade... Done  
The following packages have been kept back:  
  kubeadm kubectl kubelet  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Something common that I see that could cause this. You may have an update that’s installed but not applied. Try rebooting your system.

Comment: The upgrade window for 19.10 has long-since passed. You'll need to [follow these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/1091774) to upgrade your system, or you'll need to do a fresh install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: @Matigo Thank you, but, as I described in the question, I have done those steps and it is still not working.

Comment: Have you `sudo apt full-upgrade` to apply all upgrades for *eoan*, which must be done first.  I don't see any mention that you did that, but the error messages tells you all upgrades must be applied first.

Comment: @Taux1c Thank you for the suggestions.  I have now rebooted, done the full-upgrade, and then rebooted again.  Same results.

Comment: @Matigo How do I do a fresh install?  I am desperate enough to try anything at this point.  Earlier, I downloaded a file called ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso and put it on an external drive attached to the machine, but I have no idea what to do with it.  Is that the basis of the fresh install?

Comment: @user535733 For the sake of completeness, I wanted to show that I have an internet connection, so I looked up the names of the principal Ubuntu mirror sites in the US and did a wget to one of them.  I sincerely believe that internet connectivity is not the problem, but if there is another URL that you can suggest to demonstrate this, I will be happy to give it a try.

Comment: Connection is already demonstrated in your `sudo apt update` output: Those "hit" entries. Good thinking, though. That's the spirit!

Comment: Your output seems to show three upgradeable packages. Please add the complete output of `sudo apt full-upgrade` to your Question above.

Comment: @user535733 I don't still have the output of full-upgrade from the first time I ran it, but I ran it again and I have appended the output to the original question.  Note that I am not terribly worried about Kubernetes.  If I have to re-install it after the upgrade, so be it.

Comment: You nailed it: Those three packages are preventing the do-release-upgrade. It won't run if  ANY package isn't up-to-date. Were it my system, I would uninstall those packages, then run the do-release--upgrade, then reinstall the packages after.

Comment: @user535733 And just like that...

dalex@dalex-Lenovo-N22:~$ lsb_release -a  
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS  
Release:        20.04  
Codename:       focal  

Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The following three packages can't be upgraded, and they are preventing the upgrade to 20.04: kubeadm kubectl kubelet. These packages are not essential to the operating system, and they can be reinstalled after the upgrade. Uninstall the three packages that  can't be upgraded, and the upgrade can continue successfully.

```
sudo apt remove kubeadm kubectl kubelet
```

Here's another example of an error that occurred when trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.10 to Ubuntu 17.04.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
click-apparmor : Depends: python3-apparmor-click (= 0.3.17) but 0.3.18 is installed
libubuntu-app-launch4 : Depends: ubuntu-app-launch (= 0.12+17.04.20170404.2-0ubuntu2) but 0.9+16.10.20160928-0ubuntu1 is installed
ubuntu-app-launch-tools : Depends: ubuntu-app-launch (= 0.12+17.04.20170404.2-0ubuntu2) but 0.9+16.10.20160928-0ubuntu1 is installed
url-dispatcher-tools : Depends: url-dispatcher (= 0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu2) but 0.1+16.10.20160816.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or 
specify a solution).
```

As you can see from the error message three packages that have `16.10` in their names are preventing similar packages that have `17.04` in their names from being installed. To solve this error uninstall the three packages in the above error message that have 16.10 in their names.